# How to convert negative and comma separated values to numbers oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have values like -

43,042 
- 1
44,889
35,224
- 1,000
17,683

and the data type is obviously varchar 2.

I have to put a condition in the column to select values above 5000 but I am unable to convert it to number due to presence of commas and negative signs.
How can I convert it to number to perform this check.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your number format? commas or colon

Comment: Is the comma a group separator or a decimal separator? i.e. is the first value supposed to represent 43042 (43 thousand and a bit) or 43.042 (43 and a bit)? (And why are you storing numbers as strings anyway?)

Comment: I am not its has been predefined by the creator of the tables and I cannot change it now.

Comment: You still haven't said what the comma is supposed to represent. And whether all values in the column actually match that pattern - they are all 'numbers', represent positive and negative integers, and all have the group separator (if that's what they are) commas in the expected places. Please edit your question to give more representative data if it's more complicated than you suggested. You can also include the output of `select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'` for info.

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
    select to_number(replace(your_varchar_column,',','.')) 
from your_table
where to_number(replace(your_varchar_column,',','.')) >5000
```

Comment: Apparently, there is a space between the minus and the first digit, you should remove that too.

Comment: You're assuming the comma is supposed to be a decimal separator - which may be right, it isn't clear -  and you're converting them to periods so a default format model works? But if that is the case, using an explicit format model and specifying the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS might be  better.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function to_numeric(v in varchar2) 
return number as
   num   number;
begin
   num := to_number(v);
   return num;
exception
   when others then
      return null;
end;
/
```

Comment: Explanation on answers is always desirable.

Comment: This function will return null for all of the example values in the question.

Comment: `select * from tablename where to_numeric(columnname) > 5000` this function works with us

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions227.htm) with a suitable [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) to convert your strings to numbers:

```
to_number(your_string, '999,999,999')
```

with the appropriate number of groups and group separators. I'm assuming, given that you're looking for values above 5000, that the commas represent group separators in your string and not decimal separators. It would be safer, to avoid relying on your session NLS settings, to be more explicit about it:

```
to_number(replace(your_string, ' '), '999G999G999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
```

The slight complication in your sample data is the presence of spaces in the strings too. You can use [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions167.htm) to strip those out:

```
to_number(replace(your_string, ' '), '999,999,999')
```

so your condition could be:

```
where to_number(replace(your_string, ' '), '999,999,999') > 5000
```

or more safely:

```
where to_number(replace(your_string, ' '), '999G999G999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
  > 5000
```

Demo with your strings coming from a CTE:

```
with t (n) as (
  select '43,042 ' from dual
  union all select '- 1' from dual
  union all select '44,889' from dual
  union all select '35,224' from dual
  union all select '- 1,000' from dual
  union all select '17,683' from dual
)
select n, to_number(replace(n, ' '), '999,999,999') as converted
from t
where to_number(replace(n, ' '), '999,999,999') > 5000;

N        CONVERTED
------- ----------
43,042       43042
44,889       44889
35,224       35224
17,683       17683
```

or more safely:

```
with t (n) as (
  select '43,042 ' from dual
  union all select '- 1' from dual
  union all select '44,889' from dual
  union all select '35,224' from dual
  union all select '- 1,000' from dual
  union all select '17,683' from dual
)
select n, to_number(replace(n, ' '), '999G999G999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
  as converted
from t
where to_number(replace(n, ' '), '999G999G999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''') > 5000;
```

Of course, you should not be storing numbers as string in the first place. Use the correct data type and you don't have to deal with this sort of issue. You also don't have to worry about string which are not in the format you expect, and which can therefore cause ORA-01722 errors for many reasons... even a number that doesn't have group separators, or has them in the wrong place, will error if you've stated they should be in certain places.

Comment: It was already there I can't help it now and the method is not working its giving invalid number...

Comment: @SiddharthBhatia - then you have values that don't match that pattern. it works for the examples you gave. You could remove the commas, but do you also have decimals? The more manipulation you do of the string, the less sure you can be that the result means what you expect. And you may have things that don't look like numbers at all.

Comment: Its working when i select the data from the column but not when I use it with where , and to use it as condition @Alex Poole

Comment: Is it really working when you select every value from the column, or just when you fetch the first, say, 50 in something like SQL Developer's query result window? You may have an unconvertable string later int he result set. Or another filter condition you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Even with the 'safer' version that specifies the NLS setting?